# Make label clickable for each input

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I have the following code...

```
{%for row in odata%}
    <div class="options">
      <label for="option-text">{{row}}</label>
      <input type="radio" id="option-text" name="option-text">
    </div>
{%endfor%}
```

But for some reason even with the for loop, for each options available, clicking a label by default selects the first option (radio box). Why is that and how can I get past it?

Comment: ids must be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-using the same `id` value, over and over. Which one should be activated when you click the label? Your browser will pick the *first* element with the id named in the `for` attribute here, and if you give all `input` elements the same `id` and all `label` elements the same `for` attribute value, then you can't ever expect anything but the first `input` to be toggled.

Generate unique id values; you can use the [`for` loop special variables](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for) such as `loop.index0` to add a number to each `id`:

```html
{%for row in odata%}
    <div class="options">
      <label for="option-text-{{loop.index0}}">{{row}}</label>
      <input type="radio" id="option-text-{{loop.index0}}" name="option-text">
    </div>
{%endfor%}
```

Note that the `name` attribute stays the same! This is intentional. You may want to give those `input` elements a `value` attribute, however, for the browser to send back to the server on submit.

Another option is to forgo `for` altogether and nest the `<input>` *inside* the `<label>..</label>` tag:

```html
{%for row in odata%}
    <div class="options">
      <label>
        {{row}} <input type="radio" name="option-text">
      </label>
    </div>
{%endfor%}
```

See the [MDN documentation on `<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) for more details.